# Populate fields based on other fields ASP.NET Razor Pages

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

I know that this question might have been already on this site, but there are some different things in my approach because I use @Html.EditFor and @Html.DropDownList.
So I have a drop down list and when I choose the ID there I want to retrieve some information from the DB then populate some fields in the current form. I know that I should use JS but I don't know how.

View:

```
@model TestApp.Dtos.InsertDto
@using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div class="col-md-9">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Category, new SelectList(Model.ListOfCategory, "Text", "Text"), "-- Please select --", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control"});
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            @Html.EditFor(model => model.Car, new{htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }});
        </div>
@*And then the form continues with other fields and after that the submit button *@
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ajax to get data from backend,and put the result data into somewhere you want.Here is a simple demo to get a selectListItem from backend and put it into a div.If you want to do something more complex,you need to share the structure of `InsertDto`,and explain clearly what kind of data you will get from db and explain what does `populate some fields in the current form` mean?
View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="col-md-9">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Category, new SelectList(Model.ListOfCategory, "Text", "Text"), "-- Please select --", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" ,@onchange = "getData()" })
    </div>
    <div id="dbdata">
    </div>
}
```

js:

```
<script>
        function getData() {
           $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
               data: { Category: $("#Category").val() },
                url: '/B/GetData',
            }).done(function (result) {
                $("#dbdata").html("the selected value is " + result.text);
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Model:

```
public class InsertDto
    {
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public List<SelectListItem> ListOfCategory { get; set; }
    }
```

controller:

```
public IActionResult Index(string id)
        {
            InsertDto i = new InsertDto { ListOfCategory = new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem { Text = "t1" }, new SelectListItem { Text = "t2" }, new SelectListItem { Text = "t3" } } };
            return View(i);
        }
        public SelectListItem GetData(string Category) 
        {
            return new SelectListItem { Text = Category, Value = Category + "value" };
        }
```

result:
[image]